# How can i take first and last name after splitting this based on number?

Tags: c#

I want to take first and last name based on time.

```
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
{
  int numberOfFrnd = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  for (int j = 0; j < numberOfFrnd; j++)
  {
    var anotherInput = Console.ReadLine();
    var splitInput = anotherInput.Split(' ');
    var Fn = Convert.ToString(splitInput[0]);
    var time = Convert.ToInt32(splitInput[1]);
  }
}
```

---

```
Input : 
1
5 
Ayan  20 
Punom  11 
Eifty  9 
Prioti  15 
Surovi  12

Output : 
Ayan Eifty
```

Comment: Based on time? What time? This question doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I can't figure out how your input turns into that output.  Maybe this belongs on [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: time means the second part 20 11 9 15 12

Comment: @LarsTech My guess (based on my superior crossword and sudoku skills) is the user enters 1 and 5 which returns the lowest value name (9) and the highest value name (20) but that's a complete guess!

Comment: @DavidG That's not a bad interpretation. I couldn't get past the index value order.  Using "time" as the description didn't help either.

Comment: As pointed out by Arun Mohan, here is the [source problem](https://www.devskill.com/CodingProblems/ViewProblem/38).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility using a `List<Tuple<string, int>>` that is sorted with a lambda expression:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Tuple<string, int>> PeopleStuckInThePond = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
    Console.Write("Number of Test Cases? ");
    int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for(int i = 0; i <input; i++)
    {
        PeopleStuckInThePond.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Case " + (i + 1).ToString() + " of " + input.ToString());
        Console.Write("Number of Friends? ");
        int numberOfFrnd = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfFrnd; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("Friend " + (j + 1).ToString() + " of " + numberOfFrnd.ToString() + ": ");
            var anotherInput = Console.ReadLine();
            var splitInput = anotherInput.Split(' ');
            var Fn = Convert.ToString(splitInput[0]);
            var time = Convert.ToInt32(splitInput[1]);
            PeopleStuckInThePond.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(Fn, time));
        }
        PeopleStuckInThePond.Sort((a, b) => b.Item2.CompareTo(a.Item2));
        Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + PeopleStuckInThePond.First().Item1 + " " + PeopleStuckInThePond.Last().Item1);
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Sample output:

```
Number of Test Cases? 2
Case 1 of 2
Number of Friends? 5
Friend 1 of 5: Ayan 20
Friend 2 of 5: Punom 11
Friend 3 of 5: Eifty 9
Friend 4 of 5: Prioti 15
Friend 5 of 5: Surovi 12
Answer: Ayan Eifty

Case 2 of 2
Number of Friends? 3
Friend 1 of 3: FirstVictim 61
Friend 2 of 3: ThirdViction 32
Friend 3 of 3: SecondViction 45
Answer: FirstVictim ThirdViction

Press Enter to Quit
```